# Angular 14 authenticate Azure AD B2C login token is not expiring even after 24 hours

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, angular14

I am new to Azure AD B2C.
I have integrated my Angular app to authenticate using Azure AD B2C.
User is redirected to azure login page and everythng working fine.
But once logged in, the token never expired and even after 14 hours, i am not prompted for login.
Not sure if i have done anything wrong.

I followed the instruction in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-angular-spa-app

In azure portal, i have configured the user flow with `Access & ID token lifetime as default 60 minutes`

Can anyone please help me how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not being prompted for re-authenticating since the session cookie is still alive. [Session lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow) is managed apart from token lifetime.

You have to redirect the client to the User Journey `end_session_endpoint`. The aforementioned endpoint is found in the OpenIDC metadata document.

E.g. `https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sign_in/oauth2/v2.0/logout` found at `https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sign_in/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

For more information take a look at [Send a sign-out request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect), [Logging Out of MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/logout.md) and the [MsalService class](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/src/msal.service.ts/) `logout*` functions.